# Check if a value obtainable from arithmetic operations on array

Tags: logic, dynamic-programming

I'm sorry for not framing the title properly but it's basically this :

Given an array of size n with elements a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n-1</sub> and a value K,find out if K is obtainable by inserting + or - ( atleast one ) before each element. Print YES if obtainable else NO. It is imperative that all numbers be used.

eg:

Input :
4 6
1 2 3 4

Output :
YES

Solution : 1 - 2 + 3 + 4
Input :
4 7
1 2 3 4
Output :
NO

I felt that it was entirely possible that a dp solution could be found.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What language are you using?

Comment: Don't be sorry for not framing the title properly.  Be sorry for not posting your code that shows the effort you've given to solving this.  We're here to help - not do your homework for you.

Comment: This was a question given to me 2 years ago and I was able to brute force it with an order of 2^n which obviously worked for the smaller cases.

Comment: Do you know the maximum bound of n? If its not too large just try all the combinations.

Comment: n being 100 would give a 10^30 cases even though n isn't too large.

Comment: yeah i'm sorry about not posting the code....and I've realized that it's just a slight modification to the knapsack problem and completed it in O ( n )  time.( this one doesn't require the maximum profit possible optimization )

Answer (score 0):

This is the recursion:

```
bool Recursion( int* myarray, int result, int size ){
    myarray[0] *= -1;
    if( size == 1 ){
        if( result == myarray[0] )
            return true;
    }
    else if( Recursion( (myarray+1), (result-myarray[0]), size-1 ) ) 
        return true;

    myarray[0] *= -1;
    if( size == 1 ){
        if( result == myarray[0] )
            return true;
    }
    else if( Recursion( (myarray+1), (result-myarray[0]), size-1 ) ) 
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

This is the main implementation:

```
void printarray( int* myarray, int size ){
    for( int i = 0; i < size ; i++ ){
        std::cout << myarray[i];
        if( i != size-1 )
            std::cout << " + ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(){

    const int size = 4;
    const int result = 6;
    int myarray[size] = {1,2,3,4};

    bool test = Recursion( myarray, result, size );

    if( test ){
        std::cout << "YES... Solution: ";
        printarray( myarray, size );
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "NO... " << std::endl;
        printarray( myarray, size );
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

However, I'll leave it up to you to read it.